# Azure Data Factory Insert Child with Identity of Parent

Tags: sql-server, parent-child, azure-data-factory, master-detail

I would like to create an Azure Data Factory Pipeline that will collect a number of csv files from an Azure Storage Blob Container, and insert data into an Azure Sql database. For each file, it should:

1. Insert into parent table (CsvFiles)
2. Use the value of the identity column generated from the previous step for the foreign key (CsvFilesId) when inserting data into child table (CsvFileRows)

[image: data_model]

*CsvFiles.Id is an identity column, the value of which needs to be inserted into the foreign key column CsvFileRows.CsvFilesId*

I've not been able to find any guidance on how to compose a pipeline for what I expected to be quite a common master/detail type load.

Does anyone know of any documentation that covers this please?

Comment: Can you not create a trigger to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly simple solution, no trigger needed. I will say, it only will work if FileName is a unique value in the CvsFiles table.

[image: ADF Pipeline within For Each]
[image: Copy Data to Child Table with additional column]

Let me know if you need anything clarified, or need help with anything in detail, but this is just one simple solution that can be built within ADF entirely.

Comment: Many thanks Trent - great answer. I also found a helpful video from a youtuber that makes an excellent job of his tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsO2FHQdILs&list=PLGjZwEtPN7j8b9dPA0HrtJDptOB69B506&index=6&t=80s